# Is there a way to get a list of installed printers on a linux server from VB?

Tags: linux, vb.net, printing, cups

Is there a way to deal with a CUPS server from a program written in VBNet ?

From VBNet, I'd like to get a list of all installed printers on a linux server (a VM actually) and maybe execute some function (as cupsenable, cupsdisable, cancel, etc.) on one ...

Is there a kinda framework I could use ?...

Comment: I am a bit rusty on *nix, but [this link might be helpful](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/connecting-to-ssh-servers-in-.net.html).  In theory, it should allow you to connect and issue those commands.

Comment: Awesome !!!

I'll give it a try and tell you results :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @Jimmy Smith
AMAZING !!! IT WORKS !!
Thnx buddy !!

Comment: I had a strong feeling!  I should articulate this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the NuGet package manager, find and add SSH.NET to your project.

This should allow you to SSH the server and issue commands like follows:

```
Using ssh As New SshClient("server_host_name", "server_user_name", "server_password")
    ssh.Connect()
    Dim result = ssh.RunCommand("ls -l")  'list directory info
    ssh.Disconnect()
End Using
```

[Project's Homepage](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/)

[Example provided here](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/connecting-to-ssh-servers-in-.net.html)